# Termination of possible early pregnancy

Tags: obstetrics, contraception, cravings, pregnancy-test

I had unprotected sex with my wife about 3 weeks back. She missed her periods yesterday. In addition to this, she has been feeling weak, her appetite changed drastically, she is usually an insomniac but now is sleeping a lot. She gets food cravings at night. No breast tenderness, nauseated at times(not very much or very frequently), no morning sickness, no vomitings and mood swings.

She also has a kind of unpredictable menstrual cycle. She keeps on missing her periods randomly. Most of the symptoms she is showing are common to PMS and Pregnancy. Only today she had a pinkish brown spotting, which put me into fear. The problem is we have a strike in our city and nearly **all** of the medical stores are closed so we can't really get our hands on any pregnancy test kits right now.

If it's a pregnancy it's an unwanted one. How can I confirm this pregnancy? And if confirmed, what are the steps that I can take to terminate it **without having to go for outright abortion?**

Comment: Terminating a pregnancy is an abortion. There is nothing less than "outright." It's also a potentially dangerous procedure no matter how it's done, so don't even think about some home baked method you hear about on the internet if you value your wife's life. You can find out if your wife is pregnant by visiting a doctor or clinic that provides such services. There is no other way to confirm it other than waiting for the proof of her swelling belly.

Comment: There are ECPs (emergency contraception pills) but the longest of these are only effective for up to 120 hours after the deed. You're way past that. You will need to confirm the pregnancy and then seek professional medical advice. There is a chance your wife's symptoms are psychosomatic in nature, but a testing kit is the first stage to working out what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

Abortion can be performed chemically (ru-486, mifepriston+misoprostol if I recall correctly). Is there no urgent care or e.r. you can go to for the test?

Answer (score 0):

Most pregnancy symptoms only start to appear about 6 weeks after the last period. If she had been fertile, it would have been 2 weeks after her last period, and adding 3 weeks gets you to 5 weeks, so this would be soon to be experiencing any of them. Things like feeling weak and sleeping a lot are not generally early symptoms. Spotting is also not a sign of pregnancy. It's more likely she's just worried, especially given the history of missing periods.

There's no way to end a pregnancy (without the help of a doctor) that is both reliable and safe. Old wives tales abound, but they don't work and some are insanely dangerous, so I won't repeat any of them here. If you can't just go to a medical store and buy a pee test, then make an appointment with a doctor. They will have access to tests. A blood test for pregnancy can be done very quickly if the lab is on site - emergency rooms do them all the time before prescribing things to women who may be pregnant. It's literally "while you wait" - and you don't wait long. Another advantage of a doctor appointment is that if they tell you it's positive, you will be able to discuss next steps right then and there.